# Cassandra. Not enough replica available - Java driver behaviour different from CQL console

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a very simple cluster with 2 nodes. 
I have created a keyspace with SimpleStrategy replication and a replication factor of 2.
For reads and writes I always use the default data consistency level of ONE.

If I take down one of the two nodes, by using the datastax java driver, I can still read data but when I try to write I get "Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)".

Strangely if I execute the exactly same insert statement by using the CQL console it works without any problem. Even when using the CQL console the data consistency level was 1.

Am I missing something?

TIA

---

**Update**

I have done some more tests and the problem appears only when I use the BatchStatement. If I execute the prepared statement directly it works. Any idea ?

Here the code

```
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint("192.168.1.10")
            .addContactPoint("192.168.1.12")
            .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect();
    session.execute("use giotest");

    BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO hourly(series_id, timestamp, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        batch.add(statement.bind(new Long(i), new Date(), 2345.5));
    }

    session.execute(batch);
    batch.clear();
    session.close();
    cluster.close();
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the relevant parts of your connection, session, and write code?

Comment: I added it to the orginal post, thanks

Comment: Just spit-balling here, but try defining your nodes as a String array and use `.addContactPoints(nodes)` instead.  Now that I see your issue only happens during batch statements, it probably won't make a difference...just being thorough.

Comment: It makes no difference unfortunately. It looks like a bug in the driver to me....

Comment: It's not a driver issue: I can reproduce it in cqlsh with the `BEGIN BATCH ... APPLY BATCH` syntax. Btw it fails as soon as there is more than 1 statement in the batch. I'm investigating if Cassandra has a good reason to return that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batches are atomic by default: if the coordinator fails mid-batch, Cassandra will make sure other nodes replay the remaining requests. It uses a distributed batch log for that (see [this post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/atomic-batches-in-cassandra-1-2) for more details).

This batch log must be replicated to *at least one replica* other than the coordinator, otherwise that would defeat the above mechanism.

In your case, there is no other replica, only the coordinator. So Cassandra is telling you that it cannot provide the guarantees of an atomic batch. See also the discussion on [CASSANDRA-7870](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7870).

Comment: Last detail: this does not apply to a single-node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, make sure you have specified both hosts at the driver level.